How do I make Ffmpeg work for subtitles in flutter?
I'm trying to burn subtitles in a video. I'm going to show you the manual command I used:
String newCmd =
          '-i /storage/emulated/0/ffmpeg/video.avi -vf subtitles=\'/storage/emulated/0/ffmpeg/caption.srt\':force_style=\'Fontsize=24\' /storage/emulated/0/ffmpeg/apt.mp4';
      

When I use the above command it just fail, but the following code works.
 String newCmd =
          '-i /storage/emulated/0/ffmpeg/video.avi /storage/emulated/0/ffmpeg/apt.mp4';

When I run ffmpeg on my pc this is the command
ffmpeg -i F:\ffmpeg\video.avi -vf subtitles='F\:\\ffmpeg\\caption.srt':force_style='Fontsize=24' F:\ffmpeg\new.mp4

So when using in subtitles we need to provide extra backslashes to the paths. So does this mean Flutter expects the same? Or should I have to include a font file to it?
I'm using ffmpeg_kit_flutter package.
